# 302 Error Handling Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, get

I'm trying to implement a function which can check the validity of an access token provided as a parameter. To do this, I have to read the response of a simple GET request (graph.facebook.com/debug_token?xxxx).

Normally, it's pretty straightforward, but I had to write a weird function to loop through the redirects with curl (can't use curl follow redirection, because open base dir is always set on).

The method is working but I don't understand why my hosting service (000webhost) **always** perform a 302 redirect (which it can difficultly access the end result of) to the url error.000webhost.com.

Can you please help me solve this problem ?
Especially that the response in a browser is really simple (try it at home!)...

Thank you very much.

Comment: `open_basedir` has nothing to do with curl. Why do you think it is?

Comment: When I tried the usual "get webpage with curl" method, it dropped safe_mode / open_basedir errors, so I think it's linked...